# How to create the DBContext using REST calls

Tags: entity-framework, rest, http

I connect to my server via http call, after having connected to perform the CRUD operations on the database as I initialize the dbContext of the entity framework to use entities and repositories?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I connect via http to the server (where I have the db) after which I wanted to initialize the dbContext but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: See the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I find a solution